# axios put request in react is returning empty

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm pretty new with React and Call requests. I'm building a full stack app using React, express, MySql, and Sequelize.
Everything works fine except for the Put request to edit the client information. I'm using Axios to make those calls and I can add, see, and delete data from the app but the edit part is not working.

When hitting the submit button on the form, the Put request is returning an empty array instead of the actual modified data. My routes are Ok (I believe), as testing it with Postman work just fine. I'm almost sure that my problem is on the method being used in the axios call, but I can't just find the right way to make it work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import API from '../../utils/API';

class index extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeLastName = this.onChangeLastName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeFirstName = this.onChangeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePhone = this.onChangePhone.bind(this);
    this.onChangePetName = this.onChangePetName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeBreed = this.onChangeBreed.bind(this);
    this.onChangeNotes = this.onChangeNotes.bind(this);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        client: null
    }

}

componentDidMount() {

    let id = this.props.match.params.id
    API.getClient(id)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                client: res.data
            })
            console.log(this.state.client.id)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}


onChangeLastName(e) {
    this.setState({
        lastName: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangeFirstName(e) {
    this.setState({
        firstName: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangePhone(e) {
    this.setState({
        phone: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangePetName(e) {
    this.setState({
        petName: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangeBreed(e) {
    this.setState({
        breed: e.target.value
    });
}

onChangeNotes(e) {
    this.setState({
        notes: e.target.value
    });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let obj = {
        lastName: this.state.client.lastName.value,
        firstName: this.state.client.firstName.value,
        phone: this.state.client.phone.value,
        petName: this.state.client.petName.value,
        breed: this.state.client.breed.value,
        notes: this.state.client.notes.value
    };

    let id = this.state.client.id

    axios.put("http://localhost:3000/api/clients/" + id, obj)

        // .then(alert("client Updated"))
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    this.props.history.push('/admin');
}

render() {

    const client = this.state.client ? (
        <div className="client">
            <h3 style={{ marginLeft: "60px" }}>Update Client</h3>

            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} style={{ padding: "60px" }}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.lastName}
                        onChange={this.onChangeLastName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>First Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.firstName}
                        onChange={this.onChangeFirstName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Phone: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.phone}
                        onChange={this.onChangePhone}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Pet Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.petName}
                        onChange={this.onChangePetName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Breed: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.breed}
                        onChange={this.onChangeBreed}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Notes: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.notes}
                        onChange={this.onChangeNotes}
                    />
                </div>

                <br />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update Client" 
                     className="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    ) : (
            <div className="center">Loading Client</div>
        )

    return (


            <div className="container">
                {client}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default index;
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with above code. Can you use Network tab in Chrome's dev tool to verify your api request and response data is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming it is because of the way you are handling the onchange of your inputs.  You want to set the onchange to the client value in your state.  But instead you are setting it to the state itself.  So then when you are building your object to send to the backend you are sending null data because you haven't set any data to the actual client value in your state and it is still null.  Try console logging the state and you will see what I'm talking about.    Also you are adding a `.value` to the end each of the state values you are trying to build your object with and this is not necessary.  Finally you don't need to specify an onchange for each input just give the input a name attribute and you can set your onchange handler like so:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })
}
```

so your component would look something like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import API from '../../utils/API';

class index extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        client: null
    }

}

componentDidMount() {

    let id = this.props.match.params.id
    API.getClient(id)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                client: res.data
            })
            console.log(this.state.client.id)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}


onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        client: {
             ...this.state.client,
             [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    });
}


onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let obj = {
        lastName: this.state.client.lastName,
        firstName: this.state.client.firstName,
        phone: this.state.client.phone,
        petName: this.state.client.petName,
        breed: this.state.client.breed,
        notes: this.state.client.notes
    };

    let id = this.state.client.id

    axios.put("http://localhost:3000/api/clients/" + id, obj)

        // .then(alert("client Updated"))
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    this.props.history.push('/admin');
}

render() {

    const client = this.state.client ? (
        <div className="client">
            <h3 style={{ marginLeft: "60px" }}>Update Client</h3>

            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} style={{ padding: "60px" }}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="lastName"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.lastName}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>First Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="firstName"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.firstName}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Phone: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.phone}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Pet Name: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="petName"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.petName}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Breed: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="breed"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.breed}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Notes: </label>
                    <input type="text"
                        name="notes"
                        className="form-control"
                        defaultValue={this.state.client.notes}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                    />
                </div>

                <br />
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update Client" 
                     className="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    ) : (
            <div className="center">Loading Client</div>
        )

    return (


            <div className="container">
                {client}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default index;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I modified the code as you suggested but instead of an empty array, I'm now getting back an empty object on the console with status 200. still no modification to data

Comment: yes, Post, Get, Delete, and Put requests work just fine when using Postman. I just tried again, and Put request gets me back an object with the number 1, and when checking mysql workbench it actually changes the data, so I assume it works

Comment: Ok console.log the obj and the id before you send it in your axios request to make sure you are sending the correct data

Comment: I console logged id and it shows fine, but obj is giving me the same information that is on the database

Comment: Oh my bad I forgot to change each of the onchange handlers in your inputs to use the single onChange function.  I edited the answer.  In each of your inputs change the onchange handler to use the single onChange function

Comment: ok, now obj is console logging the changes, so the data is being sent correctly, but why is not being modified

Comment: Is the data you are posting with postman the same as the data you are sending?  In postman your sending a plain object with your information in that to the backend.  You aren't wrapping your data in a key inside that object.  Maybe try posting your server code so we can look at that as well.

Comment: yeah I got it, I just needed to add the id property to the object being sent. Thanks a lot dude, you saved my day :)

Comment: No problem glad to help. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you're calling `this.props.history.push` immediately after calling `axios.post`, essentially redirecting before the POST request has a chance to return a response.

Try putting `this.props.history.push('/admin')` inside the `.then()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing multiple thing wrong here,

For every input you should have only 1 `onChange` handler, every input have `name` attribute to work with `state`. For example,

```
<input type="text"
    className="form-control"
    defaultValue={this.state.client.lastName}
    name="lastName" //Like this should add name for every input like below
    onChange={this.onChangeHandler} //This is a common onChangeHandler for every input should add in every input like below
/>


<input type="text"
    className="form-control"
    defaultValue={this.state.client.firstName}
    name="firstName"
    onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
/>
```

And `onChangeHandler` function should be,

```
onChangeHandler(e){
   this.setState({
      ...this.state.client,
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value
   })
}
```

And finally your `onSubmit` function should be,

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let obj = {
        lastName: this.state.client.lastName, //Remove `.value` as we are getting values from state and not directly from input
        firstName: this.state.client.firstName,
        phone: this.state.client.phone,
        petName: this.state.client.petName,
        breed: this.state.client.breed,
        notes: this.state.client.notes
    };

    let id = this.state.client.id

    axios.put("http://localhost:3000/api/clients/" + id, obj)

        // .then(alert("client Updated"))
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

    this.props.history.push('/admin');
}
```

**Note:**  You won't get value here in console.log,

```
 API.getClient(id)
   .then(res => {
       this.setState({
          client: res.data
       })
       console.log(this.state.client.id)
   })
```

beacuse `seState` is `async`, you should use [`callback`](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) in `setState` to make console.log,

```
 API.getClient(id)
    .then(res => {
       this.setState({
           client: res.data
       }, () => console.log(this.state.client.id)) //This is callback
    })
```